# Laravel:prepend new log to log file

Tags: laravel, logging, bigdata, prepend, bug-tracking

I'm looking for a way to prepend (instead of append) new logs to the log file.
The problem is for the big logfile, I should scroll a lot to see new logs.

Comment: Something to be aware: Appending to a file is an operation that takes constant time. Prepending to a file means basically making a copy of the file with the new line first which will be slow for large log files. Instead you can use command line tools like `tail` to see the end of a file

Comment: In case your log is so big, you should divide log to multi file with the limited capacity. This means your current log reaches to the limited capacity which you defined before, you should write to another file. Ex: log-YYYYmmdd-1.log, log-YYYYmmdd-2.log.....log-YYYYmmdd-n.log

Answer (score 0):

First what you do is add a entry in `config/logging.php` like this:

```
'newLog' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/newLog.log'),
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    ],
```

Understand the Log level and driver system of laravel [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging).

I hope I could help you.